# google colab error while mounting google drive

Tags: google-colaboratory

I'm trying to mount my google drive in google colab but it's not working. It worked absolutely fine till yesterday. From today onwards I'm facing error. When i paste the auth code, it keeps on running the cell but never get mounted. this is the code i have been using and i generelly copy and paste auth code manually (without clicking copy button)

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

when i try debug code

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount._DEBUG = True
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

It returned this error

> bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for
> device bash: no job control in this shell

.
I dont have any idea about this .. please help

Comment: can you explain your part about when you out auth codes, where you put your auth codes

Comment: This is the code and output sir
https://extraimage.com/images/2020/10/07/colab-error.png

It keeps on running but not getting mounted.

Comment: what are you pressing after putting your authorization code, once you put your auth codes press Cntl+Enter